# sudo ошибка в etc sudo conf строка 0 при загрузке модуля sudoers_policy

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

После неправильного назначения прав, начало выдавать ошибку:

> Sudo: /usr/bin/sudo должен принадлежать пользователю с uid 0 и иметь бит  setuid.

Погуглив нашлось [решение](http://sotvm.h1n.ru/main/5-password.html) с установкой прав
, но оно тоже не работает следуя инструкциям вылезла ошибка

> Sudo: ошибка в /etc/sudo.conf, строка 0, при загрузке модуля "sudoers_policy"
>
> Sudo: usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so должен принадлежать пользователю с uid 0
>
> Sudo: фатальная ошибка, не удалось загрузить модули

Плюс к этому стало невозможно войти в систему. Выдает ошибку:

> The system is running in low-graphics mode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли что-то сделать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Записать загрузочную флешку Ubuntu, загрузиться с нее, примонтировать ваш диск и заново назначить права на /usr/bin/sudo

Comment: А есть ли подробное руководство загрузке, монтированию и назначению прав, в голове уже каша от пересмотренной инфы на форумах?

Comment: по ссылке достаточно много вариантов восстановления прав доступа а вообще если есть бекап - проще из него восстановить, чем возиться http://ru-linux.livejournal.com/2596118.html